# JPA - Query with 'composite values' in where-clause

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, criteria-api

I want to realize the following (for this example: MySQL) statement in JPA 2.1 with Eclipselink as the implementation:

```
select *
from account
where (mailing_zip_code, id) > (56237, 275)
order by mailing_zip_code asc, id asc 
limit 10;
```

What I want to achieve is an implementation of the seek method for endless scrolling without using an offset in the query. With focus on the where clause, I am not able to find a correct name for this construct. In some places it is called 'composite value', but I am not able to find results by this name, but it seems to be compliant with the SQL-92 standard.

This statement will be extended by filter parameters, so naturally I would like to build it with the JPA criteria API.

I searched the API for some time now, does anybody now if and how this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After realizing that

```
select *
from account
where (mailing_zip_code, id) > (56237, 275)
order by mailing_zip_code asc, id asc 
limit 10;
```

is just a shorter way to write

```
select *
from account
where mailing_zip_code > '56237'
or (mailing_zip_code = '56237' AND id > 276)
order by mailing_zip_code asc, id asc 
limit 10;
```

the criteria query was not that hard after all (appended just the predicate):

```
if (null != startId) {
     Predicate dateGreater = cb.greaterThan(entity.get(sortBy), startValue);

     Predicate dateEqual = cb.equal(entity.get(sortBy), startValue);
     Predicate idGreater = cb.greaterThan(entity.get("id"), startId);
     Predicate dateEqualAndIdGreater = cb.and(dateEqual, idGreater);

     cb.or(dateGreater, dateEqualAndIdGreater);
}
```

If there is a nicer way, I would be very happy to learn about it.

Comment: Your longer query will give you results where mailing_zip_code is greater than '56237' and id value is less than 276. Is the meaning of `(mailing_zip_code, id) > (x, y)`? I find that surprising.

Comment: Where do you get the 'less than 276' part from? I see a typo (276 instead of 275), but the statement clearly says `id > 276´. I found this statement in this presentation by Markus Winand: http://image.slidesharecdn.com/paginationdonethepostgresqlwayv2-130530141009-phpapp02/95/pagination-done-the-right-way-23-638.jpg?cb=1403756206 (http://de.slideshare.net/MarkusWinand/p2d2-pagination-done-the-postgresql-way?ref=http://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2013-07/pagination-done-the-postgresql-way)

Comment: Typo aside, I read the query as returning a union of the set of all accounts where mailing_zip_code is greater than '56237' (which includes id of any value) and the set of all accounts where mailing_zip_code = '56237' and id > 276

Comment: This is just pagination but I assume you are attempting to use the mailing_zip_code and id as the offset instead of the row number.  Your query is correct, but you still will probably want the 'limit' using setMaxResults on the resulting query, or look into scrollable cursors https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Pagination#Using_a_ScrollableCursor