# JPQL IN clause - Columns with null on the name

Tags: sql, spring, jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I'm trying to create a query with a IN clause that maps a table with other that have a composite key. For reference the first table maps a composite key (three columns) to `OtherTable` (contains a `OtherTableId` object).

Example:

```
select t1
from Table t1
where t1.otherTable in :listOfOtherTables;

...
List<OtherTable> listOfOtherTables= Arrays.asList(new OtherTable(...), ...);
query.setParameter("listOfOtherTables", listOfOtherTables);
```

I searched how to do this and is pretty straightforward. In fact I use this with strings with success like this:

```
select t1
from Table t1
where t1.states in :listOfStates;

...
List<String> listOfStates = Arrays.asList("A", "B");
query.setParameter("listOfStates", listOfStates);
```

When I run the first example (by the way the project is in Spring 4.2 + Weblogic 12.1.2), the transformation for the query to be executed in Oracle is this:

```
select t1
from Table t1
where (NULL, NULL NULL) IN (("value1", "value2", "value3"), ("value1", "value2", "value3), ...);
```

Where is supposed to be the column names, appears NULL.

Anyone can help me?

PS: I have tried this also:

```
select t1
from Table t1
where t1.otherTable in (:otherTableObject1, :otherTableObject2, otherTableObject3);
```

Also doesn't work.

Comment: Not all databases support this type of statement, and I don't believe it is supported in EclipseLink.  See the answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36801085/jpa-query-with-composite-values-in-where-clause

Comment: I believe that I have to make a native query to do what I want. I think it's weird JPA not support it even that not all databases support this type of statement. It would be nice throwing error instead putting null in column names.

Comment: the answer shows someone attempted to add support for EclipseLink - you might give it a shot and request it be added officially.